Prove full rank of a matrix
An $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with $m<n$ has the full row rank. Now find two matrices $Y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $Z\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times (n-m)}$ so that $AY=I_m$ and $AZ=0_{m\times(n-m)}$. Please show that $[Y \quad Z]$ is full rank.
I have an idea that $Z$ forms the null space of $A$, and $Y$ forms the range space $A$ because $$A*(A^T(AA^T)^{-1}Y)=Y.$$ In addition, because of $AY=I_m$, the rank of $Y$ must be $m$. Then, using the Rank–nullity theorem, the conclusion is proved. Can anyone help me verify the correctness of this process?

Yes, your proof is correct
